# How to compile qemu (for i386 only) on linux

Tags: qemu

I downloaded the tar.gz from qemu.org. Now how can I compile the source code only for i386 architecture?

I mean, my qemu need not be able to emulate a Power PC, Motorola 68000 or others.

I tried the steps

```
./configure
make
make install
```

But there was a failure

```
No rule to build target 'all'
```

Apart from this, the above steps compile the qemu for all architectures too.

Hope to get some help.

Comment: can you be more specific?
i.e. what version of the source did you grab, what platform are you running on, what compilers do you have installed?

Comment: I used qemu qemu-0.15.0.tar.gz on puppy linux 528. compiler was gcc that comes with puppy528. But I think, irrespective of everything else, qemu source code should compile fine at least in modest systems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Linux Machine Download Qemu Source Code and extract in directory then cd to DIR and do following:

```
./configure --disable-kvm [--prefix=PFX] [--target-list="i386-softmmu x86_64-softmmu"]
make
make install
```

Comment: How to get rid of "ERROR: unknown option [--prefix=PFX]" after running this command?

Comment: @ Amit I have the same issue. Did you find a fix for it?

Comment: this might be of help for future people. I added a comment aswell regarding a switch for /configure. http://askubuntu.com/questions/814522/error-configure-and-make-qemu/880015#880015

Answer (score 3):

first `tar` it (extract it)
then go to the directory  on shell
then 
type this commands

```
./configure --target-list=i386-softmmu
```

when build successful

press `make` and `enter`
when this done
then write

```
sudo make install
```

that's it

Answer (score 0):

For general linux,

- #tar xvzf qemu-1.4.0.tar.bz2
- #cd qemu-1.4.0
- #./configure --target-list=i386-softmmu
- #make
- #make install

For puppy linux wary 530,

- #tar xvzf qemu-1.4.0.tar.bz2
- #cd qemu-1.4.0
- #./configure --target-list=i386-softmmu
- #make
- #new2dir make install
- #cd ..
- #dir2pet qemu-1.4.0-i486

Answer (score 0):

```
./configure  --target-list=x86_64-linux-user --disable-smartcard-nss
```

This command work for me, while building Qemu 1.6 on centOS